# Prove that all subsequential limits are contained within a closed interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $a, b$ be two real numbers such that $a < b$, and suppose that $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a
sequence such that $\forall\,\, n\,\, a \leq s_n \leq b$. Prove that all subsequential limits are
contained in the closed interval $[a, b]$. (Note that, by B-W, there is at least
one subsequential limit of the sequence.)

I know that $a$ must be the infimum of sequence $s_{n}$ and $b$ must be the supremum of $s_n$. Also by the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, there must be at least one subsequence which converges, so there is at least one subsequential limit. I'm trying to prove that this subsequential limit is neither  $<a$ nor $>b$ so it must be within $[a,b]$.

Is this the right way to approach the proof?

Comment: Why is $a$ the infimum and $b$ the supremum? For example $s_n=0$ satisfies $-2000  \leq s_n \leq 2000$ but those are not the infimum and supremum.

Comment: Oh right. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Is $l$ is a subsequential limit, then there exists some subsequence $s_{k_n}$ so that
$$\lim_n s_{k_n} = l\,.$$
Now use the fact that $a \leq s_{k_n} \leq b$, and the definition or properties of limits for that (sub)sequence.

Comment: I think I just proved it. I did this proof by contradiction. I set l < a and used the definition of a limit. I set ε < (1/2)|l-a| and showed the absurdity of |snk-l| < (1/2)|l-b|. I did that similarly for l > b. As l can't be less than a or greater than b, it must be in the closed interval [a,b].